# Scala Plugin in Intellij

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I am using Scala plugin in IntelliJ. If I want to use Scala in command line, do I have to install regular scala in my machine or is there anyway I can use the Scala plugin installed in IntelliJ outside of IntelliJ?

Thanks,

Comment: If you open a Terminal window (or whatever your OS's equivalent is) and type `scala`, do you get a "Command not found" error or does it start the Scala REPL?

Comment: I don't think the scala plugin installs all the components required to run the scala REPL.

Comment: It does require Scala somewhere on your machine. If you use SBT it will seek out the installation in Ivy. If you create a stock IDEA Scala project it will have a drop down to choose all the Scala that is on your system. If you do not have one, you'll need to click on Create to locate an existing installation from your local hard drive, ivy, or maven.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to install Scala separately to be able to use it on the command line. IDEA uses  Scala via SBT, but this is not a Scala you could use from a command line. The alternative to using REPL from the IDE could be to use Scala scratch file functionality.